# Can a JNA structure support immutability?

Tags: java, jna, vulkan

A minor irritation when using JNA structures is that they are mutable (and I mean *totally* mutable) since by default all fields *must* be public and cannot be `final` (though see below).  This means that if we would like to expose a JNA structure as a DTO (data transfer object) the client can basically monkey with the data.

Consider this trivial example:

```java
class PhysicalDevice {
    private VkPhysicalDeviceLimits limits;

    public VkPhysicalDeviceLimits limits() {
        if(limits == null) {
            limits = ...    // Instantiate from API using JNA
        }
        return limits;      // <-- Anyone can fiddle with this fully mutable data!
    }
}
```

Here the `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits` is a JNA structure retrieved from the native library (thread synchronization omitted for clarity).  The accessor is lazy but the same issue applies whether it's lazy, created as a member explicitly, injected by a framework, or whatever.

If the structure consisted of just a handful of fields then we would obviously create a wrapper that properly encapsulated the underlying JNA data performing any defensive copying required.  Unfortunately this [structure](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceLimits.html) has over a hundred fields, all of which have to be public and mutable - writing a wrapper by hand would be tedious and error prone.

Of course we could simply retrieve an instance of the structure on each invocation of the `limits()` accessor but in general we want to avoid unnecessary calls to the native layer and ideally the data should be cached locally.

Couple of other notes:

- The structure is code-generated from the native C header file but could be re-generated if changes were needed.
- The data does not change over the lifetime of the application, i.e. it's basically static data.
- There are several other (equally large) structures in this API.

So how to encapsulate this data?

I can't see any way of 'cloning' a JNA structure (for example) using a copy constructor or other means?  We could do a field-by-field copy using reflection but that feels dirty?

Can the fields be made `final`?  This is mentioned as 'risky' in some of the JNA documentation but I'm unsure why.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the JNA API](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.8.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html), the `final` modifier will make a field read-only with the exception of JNA's `read()` method to populate that structure from native memory.

> Structure fields may additionally have the following modifiers:
>
> `final` JNA will overwrite the field via `read()`, but otherwise the field is not modifiable from Java. Take care when using this option, since the compiler will usually assume all accesses to the field (for a given Structure instance) have the same value. This modifier is invalid to use on J2ME.

The caution regards whether the field can change value; it can if the underlying memory changes and it is re-read.  In theory, a user could use this to bypass the read-only nature by:

- Calling the structure's `getPointer()` value
- Directly writing to native memory at the appropriate offset
- Calling the structure's `read()` method.

Is this immutable?  Probably not, but it's no different than the existing non-modular limitations where reflective access can bypass the `final` modifier. It should at least prevent "accidentally" modifying the value, which I think is the intent of immutability.

One possible thought with very little overhead would be subclassing `Structure` with something like an `ImmutableStructure` where you override `read()`; initially it allows reading values into `final` fields but then you can change a boolean before returning it to the user, turning `read()` into a no-op.  This still allows reflective access (like any Java class) but adds a further step preventing unintentional modification.

If you don't want to go that route and want a true defensive copy, you somewhat have to give up the convenience of the Structure API and go low-level and deal directly with the array/buffer of bytes that are returned from native methods.  You can do things similar to the `Structure` class by calculating field orders, getting offsets of fields (even caching them in a map for later use), and directly reading the byte values at offsets you care about with read-only getters.

Field-by-field copy (or reading from native) via reflection happens under the hood in the Structure's pointer constructor, so creating a defensive copy could be as simple as reading a byte array of the structure's size, creating a new `Memory` object and writing those bytes to it, and passing the pointer to that `Memory` to the new copy's constructor to use via `super(p)`.  There are probably more efficient ways to do that.

You might also consider simply serializing the object and deserializing it into a new object.

Comment: Cheers.  Using the pointer constructor seems the least intrusive approach.  Of course none of the solutions are particularly great because I'm abusing JNA structures for a use-case they were never intended for.

Comment: I opened up a [discussion on the jna-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/jna-users/c/dOuPb4wetZ0) on this topic.